# `*' cannot appear in a constant-expression

Tags: c++, class, constants, constant-expression

Could anyone explain me why does those errors exist during my compilation?

```
class ILI9341_due;

class LCD_ILI9341
{
private:
    ILI9341_due *tLCD;
    ILI9341_due &LCD = *tLCD;
public:
    LCD_ILI9341();
    ~LCD_ILI9341();

    void initDisplay();
    void drawMenu();


};
```

And the errors are:

```
'LCD_ILI9341::tLCD' cannot appear in a constant-expression
`*' cannot appear in a constant-expression
ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'LCD'
making 'LCD' static
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What is `LCD` going to reference?  At the time of compilation there is nothing in `tLCD`

Comment: Can't I make reference to pointer? I mean in next few lines `tLCD` is going to point at new object of class.

Comment: @NathanOliver: It's going to reference whatever `tLCD` was initialised to point to. Non-static member initialisation happens when a class object is initialised, not at compile time, and doesn't require a constant expression. It sounds like this compiler has incomplete support for it.

Comment: Or that support is disabled.  Try `--std=c++11` (or `gnu++11` or `c++14`, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler cannot initialize `ILI9341_due &LCD` with in-class initialization. Initialize it in constructor's initialization list instead.